# What is the difference between a Statistical Model and Mathematical Model?

Tags: regression

I was studying regression and came across the terms statistical and mathematical models. Can anyone please elaborate how a statistical model is different from a mathematical model?

Comment: I don't suppose there is a clear cut formal difference.  In practice, I'd say that people call something a mathematical model if it is (largely at least) derived from assumptions regarding hte system being modeled.  By contrast, a statistical model would be one which is dictated primarily dictated by the data.  Of course, there is heavy overlap between these cases.

Comment: According to wikipedia a statistical model is also a matematical one. I guess we tend to use the former for the reason given by lulu in his comment.